# Asphalt 8: Airbone

Tags: google-account

I used Google Play Games to connect to Asphalt 8: Airbone. Is there any way to export my progress to the same game on Xbox (Mircosft account)?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: The question I linked is about PC, not XBox, but it applies to any (pair of) platforms.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do cross-OS and cross-servers. You can only deal cross-OS on same servers and cross-servers but same OS but definitely in the later you're not gonna use the servers. You can only copy files if it's Android, for example, from:

```
/sdcard/Android/data/[package.name.of.app]/
```

and the game obb file from:

```
/sdcard/Android/obb/[package.name.of.app]/
```

to the other device. And other OS in a similar manner. On same server you just log in to your account and data restore happens automatically